# Angular 9.1 - Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: out-of-memory, angular-cli, heap-memory, angular9

[image]

Below screen shot shows CPU usage
[image]

Below is package.json file
[image]

Targeted only ES2015 in tsconfig.json.
Tried doing ng build --prod-- source-map=false but did not worked

Comment: This happens when you try to build the Angular application?

Comment: yes, it is happen on build angular application

Comment: I have the same issue. Please let me know if you find any solution for the same.